# Javascript: How to get this image data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I get these values of image especially the name, size, type that shows from console when I am dragging a image. And display those data to my specific div

```
 File {name: "free-windows-10-wallpaper_050549897_263.jpg", lastModified:    
 1464238729860, lastModifiedDate: Thu May 26 2016 12:58:49 GMT+0800 (Malay 
 Peninsula Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 1185535…}
 lastModified : 1464238729860
 lastModifiedDate :Thu May 26 2016 12:58:49 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time) 
 name : "free-windows-10-wallpaper_050549897_263.jpg"
 size : 1185535
 type : "image/jpeg"
 webkitRelativePath : ""
 __proto__ : File
```

This is the js code.

```
var obj = $('.drag_me');

obj.on('dragover', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css('border', '2px solid #39ADCD');

});

obj.on('drop', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css('border', '2px dotted #39ADCD');

    var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
    var file = files[0]; //<-- I need to get the size, name, image type of this image
    console.log(file);

   //upload(file);
});
```

So i can display those data to my html

```
<div class="drag_here">
    <div class="drag_me">
        <center id="center_html">
            Drag image here
         </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't you access it using `file.name`, `file.lastModified`, just before your `//upload(file)` ?

Comment: @DavidR thank you i got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it using,

```
file.name, 
file.lastModified
```

Note: you need to include it just before your `//upload(file)` statement.

HTH